# Android :Center the google map on a certain region or location

Tags: android, maps

I am developping an application using  google maps , and I want to center the map on a certain country , let's say Tunisia , how to do this ? 
Thanks.

Comment: I tried Geocoding , but encountered a little difficulty .
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());   
      List<Address> myList = geocoder.getFromLocation(33.886917,9.537499,1);
      if (myList.size() > 0) 
          System.out.println(myList.get(0).getLocality());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Google Maps V2 (which you should be), Google Maps has a number of Camera Update methods which are used to move the camera (and hence, what the user sees).

In this case, you'd want to determine the latitude and longitude of the target location, then use [CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLng%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%29).

Then, you'd use:

```
GoogleMap map = ...;
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng));
```

where lat and lng are measured in degrees (per [the LatLng documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng)).